# Use same theme in component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Im playing around with angular 4 and material 2. 
I want to make multiple theme, which I can toggle.

I've read the tutorial on angularjs and also read about themes on material 2.
I also checked the example at https://material2-app.firebaseapp.com/
But they only use one component and I want to apply the same theme to everyone. 
And I have no Idea on how to make this possible. :S

This is the structure so far. 
[image: app structure]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Optional } from '@angular/core';

import '../assets/css/styles.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<main [class.theme-dark]="isDarkTheme">
    <md-sidenav-container>
        <md-sidenav class="sidenav" #start (open)="closeStartButton.focus()">
            Start Sidenav.
            <button md-button [routerLink]="['./dashboard']" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="start.close()">Dashboard</button>
            <br>
            <button md-button #closeStartButton (click)="start.close()">Close</button>
        </md-sidenav>
        <md-toolbar color="primary">
            <button class="icon-button" (click)="start.open()">
                <i class="material-icons toolbar-menu">menu</i>
            </button>
            Test
            <span class="toolbar-filler"></span>
            <button md-button (click)="isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme">TOGGLE THEME</button>
        </md-toolbar>
        <div class="content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </md-sidenav-container>
</main>
```

**dashboard.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent {

}
```

If I understand this right its because the themes are capsulated. 
But how can I pass so when I press "toggle theme" it also applys to the other components?
Ie. when I toggle in app.component I want the same theme (app.component.scss) in dashboard.component to change from light to dark

this is what it looks like now:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to change the whole theme of your app when you click on "Toggle theme" button ?

If so, you should take a look at this link : https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes

And particularly this part :

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-theme:   mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent);

// Default theme styles.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);

$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

// Include the alternative theme styles inside of a block with a CSS class. You can make this
// CSS class whatever you want. In this example, any component inside of an element with 
// `.unicorn-dark-theme` will be affected by this alternate dark theme instead of the default theme. 
.unicorn-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

You can create multiple theme easily with the above .scss file.

And you can link them to a class easily too :

```
.unicorn-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

So, you just need to compile the .scss file, include the produced .css file into your index.html, and then add the class you want (here, it is .unicorn-dark-theme class) to your parent component template.

And if you want to go back to default theme, you just have to remove the class.

Comment: thanks, I found the silly error... Added this "  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" to the app.component.ts.